# PowerShell Set-Culture для всех пользователей

Tags: windows, powershell

Подскажите: в PowerShell есть команда Set-Culture, с помощью которой можно задать Формат. Но он применяется только к текущему пользователю. Как можно применить это на всех пользователей, в том числе и новых?

Comment: Наверное ветка реестра `[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT]` тебе должна помочь.

Comment: Нет. [HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT] не поможет:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070302-00/?p=27783
Для редактирования реестра дефолтного пользователя нужно примонтировать его куст реестра: "\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
Применить настройки к пользователю с профилем, скорее всего, можно только зайдя под этим пользователем. Ну или также примонтировав его куст реестра.